# Access the state of a Variable within a separate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, google-maps-api-3, axios

I have an issue that i have been stuck on for quite a while.

I have a CatList component that has props as a User , he has cats that share his ‘_id ’ as  ‘userId’. I render a list of the User’s cats within this component, then render the component on my MapContainer component.  OnSelect of one of the cats changes the state of activeCat to that cat’s ‘nickName’.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Dropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class CatList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            cats: [],
            activeCat: ''

        }
    }

    onClickHandler = (kitty) => {
        this.setState({ activeCat: kitty })
        console.log(kitty)
        return(
            <div>
                <card>
                    <title>{kitty.nickName}</title>
                </card>
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getCollection('All')
    }

    //get entire collection
    getCollection = (_Id) => {

        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/kittys/getByUserId/${this.props.user._id}`)
            .then(res => {
                const cats = res.data
                this.setState({cats: cats})
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p style={{display:"flex", justifyContent:"center"}}>Selected Cat: {this.state.activeCat.nickName}</p>

                <Dropdown
                    style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "center"
                }}
                    className="cat-list">
                    <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
                        My Cats
                    </Dropdown.Toggle>
                    <Dropdown.Menu>
                        {this
                            .state
                            .cats
                            .map((kitty, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <div >
                                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => this.onClickHandler(kitty)}>{kitty.nickName}</Dropdown.Item>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })}
                    </Dropdown.Menu>
                </Dropdown>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

this code above is my CatList component. Where I render a dropdown containing the user's cat's that match his _id.

I have a MapContainer component, which is where I render my  When i console log on the MapContainer it only shows my user's information. I want the name of the cat that is chosen to go to the MapContainer as well.  With that cat name, I want to grab the cat with the matching Name from the database to be rendered on a card.

Here is my MapContainer

```
    getActiveCat = (_Id) => {
        console.log(this.props.user)
        console.log(this.state.cats)

        
         axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/kittys/getByUserId/${this.props.user._id}/${activeCat.nickName}`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log('you will see me', res.data)
                const cats = res.data
                console.log(cats)
                this.setState({cats: cats})
                console.log(cats[1].dateModified)
            })
    }
```

Then i want that cat's info to be rendered in the InfoWindow popup on my map.

Here is the infowindow code

```
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Strays
                <span role="img" aria-label="cat"></span>
            </h1>
            <Locate panTo={panTo}/>
            <Search  panTo={panTo}/>
            <CatList user = {user}  />

            <GoogleMap
            
                mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
                zoom={100}
                center={center}
                options={options}
                onClick={onMapClick}
                onLoad={onMapLoad}>
                    
                {markers.map((marker) => (<Marker
                    key={marker
                    .time
                    .toISOString()}
                    position
                    ={{
                    lat: marker.lat,
                    lng: marker.lng
                }}
                    onClick=
                    {()=>{ setSelected(marker) }}
                    icon={{
                    url: `/pawprint.svg`,
                    origin: new window
                        .google
                        .maps
                        .Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new window
                        .google
                        .maps
                        .Point(15, 15),
                    scaledSize: new window
                        .google
                        .maps
                        .Size(30, 30)
                }}/>))}

                {selected
                    ? (
                        <InfoWindow
                            position={{
                            lat: selected.lat,
                            lng: selected.lng
                        }}
                            onCloseClick={() => {
                            setSelected(null);
                        }}>
                            <div>
                                <p>Spotted {user.firstName} </p>
                            </div>
                        </InfoWindow>
                    )
                    : null}

            </GoogleMap>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can use `useContext` hook to easily access your state variables at other components. It makes it very easy if you have many levels between components which makes using `props` hard to manage / maintain.

Comment: @ozgur is it possible for me to just pass that "onClickHandler" from Catlist to MapContainer

Comment: yes, just use `props`. Here is a nice article about using props on class based components. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component

Comment: @ozgur Yeah, this has me stumped. I can not get that Cat's info to save my life.

Comment: I couldn't clearly understand how your components are nested. But the idea is you can pass down any state variables or functions to one level deep component using props. So the componet which calls InfoWindow must already have access to onClickHandler you mentioned. So that it can mount InfoWindow like this `<InfoWindow onClickHandler={clickHandlerPointer}`. You need to change clickHandlerPointer to the props variable that you use.

Comment: @ozgur that gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClickHandler' of undefined" I am not pulling the function in properly

Comment: @ozgur any change we could chat somewhere and you could help me get through this? I am completely lost

Comment: Can you get your components running at https://codesandbox.io/ ?